# Java is blocking signed certificates

Tags: java, security

I am using I.E. 11 and have just reinstalled Java 7.51

My security settings for the browser are the lowest default possible and under the Java  in the Control Panel I have set the security to medium (the lowest) as well.

When I try to run any Java apps I get this (ironically trying to run Java uninstall)

[image: Error Message]

How do I get to the point where the app will run after a prompt?

Comment: Which version of Java? Is it self signed?

Comment: It is Java version 7 update 51. It should not be self signed, I cannot run any Java apps whatsoever. The company that produces the app I need to be able to run just obtained a signature. But I cannot even run the verify version of Java app on the Java website.

Comment: You may need to add the site address to your exception list (Java control panel / security tab).

Comment: Okay, I tired that before I reinstalled Java and it had not worked. Gave it a shot and everything works fine! Put that in an answer and I will accept it. Thank you!

Comment: You might also be interested in [Java’s Losing Security Legacy](http://threatpost.com/javas-losing-security-legacy).